# Return XML which contains node from XML column

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a SQL Server table with an XML column like this:

```
create table tab
(
     Id int, 
     Title nvarchar(200), 
     XmlCol xml
)
```

I need to return an XML like this

```
<tabs>
    <tab Id="1" Title="Some Title">
        <xmlcontent>...</xmlcontent>
        <xmlcontent>...</xmlcontent>
        <xmlcontent>...</xmlcontent>
    </tab>
</tabs>
```

My best approach so far is:

```
select Id, Title, XmlCol.Query('xmlcontent')
from tab
for xml raw('tab'), root('tabs')
```

but I am getting this:

```
<tabs>
    <tab Id="1" Title="Some Title">
        <XmlCol>
            <xmlcontent>...</xmlcontent>
            <xmlcontent>...</xmlcontent>
            <xmlcontent>...</xmlcontent>
        <XmlCol>
    </tab>
</tabs>
```

XmlCol column contains XML data like this (not well-formed)

```
 <xmlcontent>...</xmlcontent>
 <xmlcontent>...</xmlcontent>
 <xmlcontent>...</xmlcontent>
```

Any idea how to flatten the structure to omit the XmlCol node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @tab table(Id int, Title nvarchar(200), XmlCol xml);
insert into @tab(id, Title, XmlCol)
values(1, N'1 Title test 1', N'<xmlcontent><e1 x="1">a</e1><e2 x="1" y="2">b</e2><test>a test</test> xmlcontent1 text</xmlcontent>'),
(2, N'2 Title test 2', N'<xmlcontent><e1 x="1">111</e1><e2 x="1" y="2">222</e2><test>333</test>xmlcontent2 text</xmlcontent>');

select Id, Title, XmlCol.query('xmlcontent/node()')
from @tab as tab
for xml raw('tab'), root('tabs');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
SELECT Id, Title , XmlCol.query('//xmlcontent')
FROM tab
FOR XML RAW('tab'), ROOT('tabs');
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=da43cf1c90da07dca2cd21aabc9bcdf8)**

Output:

```
<tabs>
  <tab Id="1" Title="Some Title">
     <xmlcontent>...</xmlcontent>
     <xmlcontent>...</xmlcontent>
     <xmlcontent>...</xmlcontent>
  </tab>
</tabs>
```